# Transforming a List<Object> into a Map<key, List<Object>> using an object's attribute as key

Tags: java, java-8

I have an object Foo with the following elements:

```
class Foo {
    int id;
    int departmentId;
    boolean condition1;
    boolean condition2;
    boolean condition3;
    //...
}
```

and a list of Foo objects (~10k entries):

```
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
fooList.add(...);
//...
```

I need to iterate through each of the departmentIds of this list, and be able to stop any further iterations of a particular departmentId once its objects meet a particular combination of conditions.

For this purpose, I was thinking to simply create a new Map which holds my departmentId as a key and all related Foo objects as its value. So that I could iterate through my new objects based on the departmentId, and easily stop the iteration for other departments with same Id once the condition is met. Something like:

```
Map<Foo.departmentId, List<Foo>> departmentFoos = new HashMap<>();
```

Can this be achieved in a better way other than iterating through my fooList and putting/replacing the object of my HashMap one by one?

Comment: By `Set`, do you *actually* mean `Map`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just edited my post - thank you

Comment: "stop the iteration for other departments with same Id" ... this is ambiguous. Why are there _other_ departments with the _same_ id and when you want to stop iterating, do you mean you only want to find exactly one `Foo`? Then why would you need a Map?

Comment: OP doesn't say that there are other departments with the same ID, just that there are other Foo's with the same departmentId, which sounds reasonable enough.

Comment: @jas Yes he does. You assume the "departments" from the quote is meant to be "Foo", and it is reasonable to assume that, but that's not what OP wrote.

Comment: Quite true, @Tom, I see your point. I was assuming without even realising it. Agree that it's good to clarify these things.

Comment: departmentId is not unique, there can be 100 Foo objects of same departmentId but different conditions. If some conditions are met for a particular departmentId, no other Foo objects of similar departmentId shall be further checked.

Comment: @CoffeeCups You can formulate the `Map` that you are looking for using `Collectors.groupingBy` while streaming the initial `List<Foo>`. After which, you can iterate over the (key, val) pairs and iterate further on the `val` to find `anyMatch` and break further traversal.

Answer (score 2):

So in terms of number of iterations, it's unlikely that converting to a `Map` would give you any benefit, you're better off just going through the list and processing in place. This is required because there's no way to know if you've reached the last appearance of a specific departmentId until you've gone through the entire list of `Foo`s.

So I would do something like:

```
for (Foo foo : fooList) {
  if (hasBeenProcessed(foo.departmentId) {
    continue;
  }
  process(foo);
}
```

Note that `hasBeenProcessed` could be as simple as `processedDepartmentIds.contains(foo.departmentId)` depending on your needs.

For just converting it to a map, there's nothing that can avoid going through the whole list. There are convenience methods for this in libraries like [Guava: Maps.toMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#toMap-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-) or [Guava: Multimaps.index](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-).

Answer (score 1):

Using Streams, It can be done this way:

```java
Map<Integer, List<Foo>> output = fooList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getDepartmentId, Collectors.toList()));
```